# Prevent 2 people from updating same row at once in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in PhpMyAdmin and agents go in and edit a field in each row with something like a "yes" or "no".

Since all agents are working on the same table in PhpMyAdmin at the same time is there any way to prevent an agent from editing the field in a specific row if another agent is editing that field in that row?

I want to prevent rework from happening.

No, I cannot have each agent have their own table - in case someone asks that.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to accomplish this.

Comment: No, you cant do it. When 2 Agents start the edit at the same time and one of them stored the record so agent 2 can store it a few minutes later.

The only way is to do it in an application with a timestamp in each row. Read them when you show the record and when he write it back put it in the WHERE  like WHERE changetime = xxxx , so has someone othe write it before the timestamp also changed and he cant write.

Comment: If agents are users, I think that's not possible. phpMyAdmin does not keep data in sync via ajax. You may look at what google spreadsheet has done if you want to build a custom solution. At most you can lock the table and raise errors.

Comment: Or you can have fake tables for each agent, and import and export scripts to sync to the real table

Comment: If you have multiple people accessing your database and you have application logic, you **really** need something better than phpMyAdmin. You probably need to build a simple front-end application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. You might need a tiny little UI program that allows agents to open a row (which would lock it by updating a Boolean or something) and prevent another agent from opening the row. Saving/Canceling would unlock it.